# JTextField data in different frames, with data stored in global variable?

Tags: java, variables

I have 2 frames each with 1 textfield, I want to capture in the first frame textfield of one a string and pass it to another frame in the textfield, but save the data in a global variable type String.

(Sorry for my english)

Comment: make your frames public

Comment: Show us what you tryed to do...

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels why?

Comment: @madhawapriyashantha: because as your program scales up larger, making fields public allows for possibility of unwanted side effects and increases the number of connections and complexity, increasing the risk of bugs. This goes to the core of Java and OOP principles, something I would assume that you know if you're answering Java questions here.

Comment: I put down a small part readable code

Comment: ///frame send "principio" //////////////

        here i have txtingress                                ///////////frame receives "date_1" ///////////

principio obj = new principio();
String fin2 = obj.txtingress.getText();

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels  i found this method from stackoverflow but it's about c# and concept was same.

Comment: Look up the singleton pattern, and how it may be applicable to your case. Singleton's have their drawbacks, but there are (much as some people like to oppose it) times when a single registry of global-style variables is a good idea... the trick is to understand your particular scenario and the implications.

Comment: jFrame2.textfield1.setText(jFrame1.textfield1.gettext()); ///////i tried with this code and not working

Comment: @dbmz make your textfield1 in jframe1 public

Comment: ready, not working in public, in frame 2 i have a global variable String receive; in the frame 1 a textfield call send, the textfield send must send data to frame 2 in the variable receive. NOTE: my textfield are public.

Comment: dbmz, although @madhawapriyashantha means well, his recommendations are misleading and potentially dangerous. The solution is almost definitely not to make anything public. I again implore him not to mislead newbies by giving recommendations on subjects that he is not very familiar with such as object oriented programming and sharing of information as it pertains to Java.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels every frames are public in netbeans by default and your recommendation surely far and far better than mine but op doesn't use your suggestion at that time .see op's answer and op have status that "I RESOLVE THE PROBLEM".

Answer (score 1):

Java doesn't have "global" variables, and you will not want to use this. Rather you will want to structure your code somewhat along the M-V-C model (model-view-control), and hold the key text String in your model. Then you can have any GUI window you wish listen to the model for changes to this variable, and they can then react accordingly.

If all you want to do is to have your two JTextFields share the exact same text, another thing you can do is have them share the same model -- Document for JTextFields.

On a side, note, you will rarely want your GUI to have more than one JFrame displaying at the same time. If you need a second dependent window, go for a dialog such as a JDialog.

---

**Edit**
For example

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.SwingPropertyChangeSupport;

public class SharedData {
   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      SimpleModel model = new SimpleModel();
      MyPanel1 panel1 = new MyPanel1(model);
      MyPanel2 panel2 = new MyPanel2(model);

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("SharedData");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(panel1);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);

      JDialog dialog = new JDialog(frame, "Dialog", false);
      dialog.getContentPane().add(panel2);
      dialog.pack();
      dialog.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}

class MyPanel2 extends JPanel {
   private JTextField field = new JTextField(10);
   private UpdateAction updateAction = new UpdateAction("Update");
   private JButton updateDataBtn = new JButton(updateAction);
   private SimpleModel model;

   public MyPanel2(SimpleModel model) {
      this.model = model;
      field.addActionListener(updateAction);

      add(field);
      add(updateDataBtn);
   }

   private class UpdateAction extends AbstractAction {
      public UpdateAction(String name) {
         super(name);
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         if (model != null) {
            model.setMyText(field.getText());
         }
      }
   }

}

class MyPanel1 extends JPanel {
   private JTextField field = new JTextField(10);
   private SimpleModel model;

   public MyPanel1(SimpleModel model) {
      field.setFocusable(false);
      this.model = model;
      add(field);

      model.addPropertyChangeListener(new ModelListener());
   }

   private class ModelListener implements PropertyChangeListener {
      @Override
      public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
         if (SimpleModel.MY_TEXT.equals(evt.getPropertyName())) {
            field.setText(model.getMyText());
         }
      }
   }

}

class SimpleModel {
   public static final String MY_TEXT = "my text";
   private SwingPropertyChangeSupport support = new SwingPropertyChangeSupport(this);
   private String myText = "";

   public String getMyText() {
      return myText;
   }

   public void setMyText(String myText) {
      String oldValue = this.myText;
      String newValue = myText;
      this.myText = myText;
      support.firePropertyChange(MY_TEXT, oldValue, newValue);
   }

   public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
      support.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
   }

   public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
      support.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
   }

}
```

---

**Edit 2**
If you want both JTextFields to share the same data as the user types it in, then have them share models (Documents for JTextFields). For example

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class SharedData2 {
   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      JTextField field1 = new JTextField(10);
      JTextField field2 = new JTextField(10);

      // ******** key below
      field2.setDocument(field1.getDocument());

      JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
      JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();

      panel1.add(field1);
      panel2.add(field2);

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("SharedData2");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(panel1);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);

      JDialog dialog = new JDialog(frame, "Dialog", false);
      dialog.add(panel2);
      dialog.pack();
      int x = frame.getLocation().x + 200;
      int y = frame.getLocation().y + 200;

      dialog.setLocation(x, y);
      dialog.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I RESOLVE THE PROBLEM.

////frame 1(principio.java) send /// this frame send the content

```
private void txtingresaKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                      
        if(evt.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
        fecha_1 obj = new fecha_1();
        obj.setVisible(true);
        fecha_1.txtfin.setText(txtingresa.getText());
        this.setVisible(false);
        }
    }
```

///////frame 2(fecha_1.java) receive the content//////////

```
private void txtfinKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                  
    if(evt.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
        periodo();
        txtini.setText(null);
        String fu = principio.txtingresa.getText();
        txtfin.setText(fu);//INGRESA REPETIDAMENTE EL VALOR INGRESADO EN PRINCIPIO CAJA TXTINGRESA

    }
}
```

//code repeats but never delete the default content that gave him the first form (principio.java)

Comment: You should never use a KeyListener in a JTextField as it will mess up the JTextField's processing of text (which goes through key bindings). Better to add an ActionListener to your JTextField as this will be activated on pressing the enter key.